# How to add data into database while applying Sessions

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am trying to create a project for lecturers managing examination papers as my first PHP project. So far I have successfully created an add_user.php applying prepared statements that worked fine at first. Then I included session_start() into add_user.php, and after submitting the form nothing seemed to happen.

No error popped up, yet the success statement didn't pop up either. I checked the database, and yes, it was empty. I'm still trying to figure out what exactly went wrong. If its the session, how do I properly implement sessions so it would not tamper with the functions? Looked up a couple of references and tutorials on sessions, to find they mostly explain the basics of how to apply sessions.

Appreciate really if someone could assist me on this. I'm new to PHP and still have lots to learn.

auth.php:

```
   <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?>
```

adduser.php:

```
 <?php  
session_start();
require('dbconnect.php');
include('header.php');

$status = "";
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['userid'])){
        // removes backslashes

//escapes special characters in a string
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userid']); 
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,md5($_POST['password']));    
$usertype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['usertype']);
$trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


$query = "INSERT into `users` (name, user_id, email, password, user_type, trn_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
   if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
        echo "SQL Query Failure";
   } 
   else if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $name, $userid, $email, $password, $usertype, $trn_date);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
<h3>You are registered successfully.</h3>
<br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
       }         
        } else {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row main">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="main-login main-center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Register Subject
            </div>
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="cols-lg-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="cols-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Enter user Name"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userid" class="cols-lg-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="cols-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userid" id="userid"  placeholder="Enter User ID"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="cols-lg-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="cols-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Enter user Email"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="cols-lg-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="cols-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Enter user Password"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirm" class="cols-lg-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="cols-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm" id="confirm"  placeholder="Confirm user Password"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cols-lg-10">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>User Role</label>
                                    <select name="usertype" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="lect">Lecturer</option>  
                                        <option value="cord">Exam Coordinator</option>                          
                                    </select>
                              </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-register">
                        <a href="index.php">Login</a>
                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: A few quick things, your header in auth.php won't work if you dont have ob_start; at the start of the page. Also, why do you even need to call session_start() if you are not referring to your session data in the script for adduser.php? Finally, when are you calling auth.php and adduser.php? I don't see their connection.

Comment: @TheInterloper so it would be ob_start() then session_start()? I added it for access security, so only an admin has access to adduser.php.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I gave this a hard look, and there's a lot of missing information here for someone to be able to help you completely. I'll give you the best I can based on the above, but you'll have some trialing to do after that and some research to do as well.

First, your error is not because you included `session_start();` It doesn't even look like you refer to the session after, so that function is useless in your current script. If you had `if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])){}` (or whatever you set in your session field) at the top to see if the user is logged in, then you would have a reason to include it. Right now it's doing nothing.

Second, I assume you would like the field in the html form to post to the php handler at the top of the page, but you don't define that. You have `action="#"`, but if you want it to post to the same page you need `action="< ? php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` in your form tag. Then at the top of the page, wrap your php in `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){`. In this instance, the form material will be posted and handled by the same page. Currently you just have `if(isset($_POST['userID']))` but unless you posted `userID` from a different page to `adduser.php`, nothing will be set.

It doesn't matter the order of `ob_start()` or `session_start()`, but `ob_start()` needs to be there for a header to be processed. This is a quick Google or Stack Overflow search, so it shouldn't be hard to find examples.

You should test your `adduser.php` page independent of your other pages, as they are different issues. You have a few issues on each page that are going to complicate your troubleshooting, so just handle them one at a time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use an empty `action` attribute, or `#`.  The form will post to the current URL.